# Merge from 1 table to another

Tags: sql

I have the following two tables:

```
table 1                   table 2
+-------------+------+    +-------------+------+
|     ssn     |  id  |    |     ssn     |  id  | 
+-------------+------+    +-------------+------+
|  123456789  |  123 |    |  123456789  |  k12 |
|  123456789  |  456 |    |  999999999  |  k11 |
|  123456789  |  789 |    +-------------+------+
|  123456789  |  k12 |
|  999999999  |  799 |
+-------------+------+
```

What I want to do is to merge the data in table 2 with the data in table 1 if there is no matching id. So 123456789 should be ignored as the member already shows with the id k12. Record 999999999 k11 should be added to table 1.

Answer (score 2):

A few ways to do this.  Here's one using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
SELECT T2.ssn, T2.id
FROM Table2 T2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Table1 T1
    WHERE T1.id = T2.id)
```

Or you could use `NOT IN`:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT ssn, id
FROM Table2
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO @Table1
( ssn, id)
SELECT t2.ssn, t2.id
FROM @table2 as t2
LEFT JOIN @table1 as t1
    ON t1.id = t2.id or t1.ssn = t2.ssn
WHERE t1.id IS NULL;
```

if you are worried about duplicates in either id OR ssn, this will only insert when both are unique

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you need to do often on large tables, this LEFT JOIN approach may perform a bit faster.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
SELECT T2.ssn, T2.id
FROM Table2 T2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```